# partial signature (of P2SH) in Bitcore. howto?

Tags: multi-signature, signature, p2sh, bitcore

Using `pybitcointools`, it is easy get partial signatures of a p2sh using the `multisign` function. Then, these can be communicated around to the several controllers of the p2sh address.

Using `bitcore`, I can sign a p2sh (using ... .`sign(privkey)`) but I do not manage to get a partial signature object, separate of the transaction itself, which I could send to other owners of the p2sh address (who could be using `pybitcointools` for instance).

How do you go about getting partial signatures of p2sh in bitcore please? 
(What am I getting wrong?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out [here](https://bitcore.io/api/lib/transaction):

```
var signature = tx.getSignatures(privKey)[0].signature;
```

gives you the signature associate with the private key!